# How to set the value of a web.xml context-param using XSLT and ANT?

Tags: xslt, ant

I am looking for an XSLT snippet that can modify the value of a context-param element typcially found web.xml files. In my web.xml I have the following context param

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>App Name</display-name>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>dojoUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>/dojo/src/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js</param-value>
 </context-param>
</web-app>
```

What I want to do is to change the value of this context-param for production to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>App Name</display-name>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>dojoUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js</param-value>
 </context-param>
</web-app>
```

The plan is to use an ANT script with the XSLT task, problem is I don't know XSLT. I need to be able to change the param-value element only if the param-name is dojoUrl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:context-param[w:param-name='dojoUrl']/w:param-value">
    <xsl:copy>/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Short explanation:

The first template copies every XML node to the output that does not match any other template (it's called the *identity template*, look it up if you are interested).

The second template specifically matches `<w:param-value>` children of `<w:context-param>` elements with a `w:param-name` of `'dojoUrl'`. It outputs a new `<w:param-value>` with a different path.

Comment: thanks I tried it out with the ant task  <xslt style="web.xsl" in="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml" out="test.xml"></xslt> but it does not work something is wrong with the match expression for the second template

Comment: @ams Works for me, the match expression is valid. Cross-check here: http://www.shell-tools.net/index.php?op=xslt - just copy/paste the XML and XSLT and see for yourself.

Comment: context-param is not the root element that is why I think the match does not work, the root element of the web.xml is web-app

Comment: @ams That does not make any difference.

Comment: I tried it out on the shell tools site without the web-app root element it works, but with the web-app root element it does not work I wish I know more about XSTL to figure it out. I updated the XML snippet in the question to include the open close <web-app> tags.

Comment: Failure to understand XML namespaces is the number one cause of bankruptcy and failed marriages. True story.

Comment: @lwburk how do I make the match expression not care about the namespace, I know XML namespaces but not XSLT

Comment: @lwburk LOL! Not mentioning the full XML along the question is number two. :)

Comment: @ams - As of 13 seconds ago, Tomalak has provided your answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone, really appreciate the help, XSLT is one of those things that has been on my list of things to get into someday for about 10 years :)